# NameError (uninitialized constant *nameofcontroller* error in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to RoR and trying simple CRUD operations without scafolding. I have a model called ccword, with controller named WordsController.

Problem is I am creating simple 'create' and leading me to this error:
 NameError in C cwordsController#create

uninitialized constant CCwordsController

This is how my create method in my controller looks like:

```
def create
  @ccword = CCword.new(params[:ccword])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @ccword.save
        flash[:notice] = 'Word was successfully added.'
        format.html { redirect_to(@ccword) }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @ccword, :status => :created, :location => @ccword }
      else
        flash[:notice] = 'Error.'
        format.html { render :action => "show" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @ccword.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }

      end
    end
  end  
end
```

my view new.html.erb looks like :

```
<h1>Words new</h1>


<% form_for (@ccword) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_messages %>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :word %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :word %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :meaning %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :meaning %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.submit 'create' %>
  </p>

  <% end %>
```

When I click create I get above NameError.
In console following log gets displayed:

```
Processing ApplicationController#create (for 127.0.0.1 at 2009-11-19 09:33:06) [POST]
  Parameters: {
    "commit"=>"Create", 
    "authenticity_token"=>"hqf54HkXSaTPGejGSbEPcw3ZpOy1Ayp3gvti29gc7Eg=", 
    "c_cword"=>{"meaning"=>"2", "word"=>"2"}
  }

NameError (uninitialized constant CCwordsController):
```

Any idea?

Comment: you need to read the directions on how to format code in you question

Comment: What's the name of your controller?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
format.html { redirect_to(@ccword) }
```

try changing it to

```
format.html { redirect_to word_path(@ccword) }
```